# Return object from forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to construct an object from the return of a forEach? How I'm doing:

```
const data = {}
object.rules.forEach(rule => {
  data[rule.name] = { body: [], type: rule.type }
})
```

How I would like to do:

```
const data = object.rules.forEach(rule => {
  data[rule.name] = { body: [], type: rule.type }
})
```

Comment: Just use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of `forEach`

Comment: forEach() never provides a return. Try for...in

Comment: Isnt map for arrays?

Comment: IUPI! With reduce is working! I didn't know that I could use reduce like that!. I will up all questions, but accept the oldest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const data = object.rules.reduce((obj, rule) => {
  obj[rule.name] = { body: [], type: rule.type }
  return obj;
}, {})
```

and shorter version

```
const data = object.rules.reduce((obj, rule) => Object.assign({}, obj, {[rule.name]:{ body: [], type: rule.type } }), {})
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to convert an array into another structure that isn't an array, [reduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is your friend.

```js
console.log(
  ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((obj, char, index) => {
    obj[char] = index;
    return obj;
  }, {})
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use `forEach` for this purpose. Calling `forEach` on an array object applies the callback function you supply to `forEach` at each element in the array object.

You could use `reduce` for this purpose, which

> applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the
>   array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value

```
const data = object.rules.reduce(function(obj, rule) {
    obj[rule.name] = { body: [], type: rule.type }
    return obj;
}, {});
```

For a detailed explanation about this method please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for single objects.

```
const data = Object.assign(...object.rules.map(
    rule => ({ [rule.name]: { body: [], type: rule.type } }))
);
```

with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `name` and `type` and [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
const data = Object.assign(...object.rules.map(
    ({ name, type }) => ({ [name]: { body: [], type } }))
);
```

Comment: Interesting, but harder to read. Still, very good to know, you deserve a up vote for that :D

Comment: it's a matter of experience.